# Human/Saiyan hybrid reproduction

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Ok, everyone that paid attention to DBZ understands that humans and saiyans can reproduce and when they do, a half-human/half-saiyan is born.  In DBGT(non-canonical) and DB: A Hero's Legacy(also non-canonical), we see the Saiyan bloodline extremely diluted.

My question is, why is only the saiyan blood diluted when a human and saiyan reproduce.  Based on the basic crossbreeding laws, the full blooded saiyan and the full blooded human will always produce a half-saiyan/half-human.  However if a half-human/half-saiyan breeds with a half-human/half-saiyan, there's a 50/50 shot at reproducing another half-saiyan/half-human.

So, my question is, if they were to continue to reproduce, wouldn't it be the human blood that eventually diluted itself out and the saiyan blood become pure once again?  Thus leading to the reemergence of the saiyan race?  Or am I just too ignorant about crossbreeding?

Comment: your right about how breeding works, the reason we see the sayian blood breading out though is because a halfsayan/halfhuman breading with a full human (an example of this is Pan from GT) they are only 1/4th sayian now, and pans kids when she breads with a full human will be 1/8th sayian which is why the dilution happens, the halfblood sayians arnt marrying each other their marrying other humans diluting the sayian genes out of them.

Comment: also when you mix a hybred with a hybred you get 1 out of 4 pure blood sayian, 1 out of 4 pure human, 2 out of 4 half blood. so  on average hybreds marrying hybreds would just keep hybreds around, with a few scattered full blood sayians and a few scattered normal humans,  however this is genetics at the most basic levels, when talking about cross specie genetics like this their millions of variables and relationships to take into account for the purity of each childs blood.

Comment: But, say if Goten and Bra began mating and reproducing, in theory, wouldn't they be able to restart the full blooded Saiyan race?

Comment: they could, but it would involve inbreading, starting a species from 2 people involves mom + son, dad + daughter, niece plus uncle ect. since we only have 2 purebloods, vegita and goku.

Comment: ...They could never go back to "full blooded". That's like saying if you've got 16 dogs that are 1/4 basenji you could eventually breed them in some pyramid scheme, resulting in at least 1 purebred basenji. Doesn't work that way. Goten and Bra are 1/2 and 1/4 Saiyan respectively, the best they can achieve is 3/8 Saijan.

Comment: It's like creatively mixing wine with beer to eventually achieve 100% alcohol.

Comment: Bra is a half Saiyan, she's Vegeta's and Bulma's daughter.  Perhaps I should have used the anime name of Bulla instead?

Comment: Wrong Saiyan on my part, apologies. I was thinking about Pan. Regardless, two half-breeds don't add up to a full breed, they add up to another half-breed.

Comment: Ok, so two half breeds will always produce a half breed then?

Comment: in simple genetics 2 half breeds can bread a full breed, the best way would be for goku and vegita to have a ton of kids, then have kids with their daughters, that would be the easiest way to purify their line.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, questions based on incorrect premises/theories [should be downvoted, not closed](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/how-do-we-handle-questions-based-on-incorrect-premise)

Comment: How is it an incorrect premise or theory though?  What's incorrect about it?

Comment: @Robert Yes, two half-breeds make a half-breed. You could get into back-breeding and further cross-breeding with other related breeds but this is clearly not an on-topic question.

Comment: You're right, my question is strictly about saiyan-human hybrids

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't know. I'm just pointing out that the VTC is not warranted.

Comment: @phantom42 no need to apologize, I was just looking for clarification as to what you meant.

Comment: Not sure why the question is getting downvoted or voted to close though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how breeding works, Himarm and Robert; that's how *some* genes work.  In situations of breeding between different types of things, the child is treated as the average of the parents; I.E. the child of a Native American and a European is considered half European/ half Native American, then if this resultant child later bred with a European it'd be 1/4 Native American, 3/4 European. I give this example because this train of thought is the same which led to the use of Blood Quantum Levels in the past in the U.S.

A half- can never produce a full-blooded individual, and thus each generation can only get closer (by half of what remains) to full-blooded.  In the case of the Saiyans, being as there are only five full-blooded members and no full-blooded females, they can not rise again without cloning or other futuristic technologies.

Comment: So again, if two half breeds begin reproducing, the only thing they'll reproduce is a half-breed?

Comment: this is wrong, since goku could have a child with a daughter of his, that child would be 3/4 sayian, then that child and goku could have another child which would be even more pure. eventually youd run into a situation where they are 99.9999% pure, essentially a new pureblood.

Comment: but again, the genetics of 2 different species is alot harder to actually determine.

Comment: Bingo, Robert. And that's still not pure, Himarm.
Incidentally, most Native Tribes use jus sanguinis now.

Comment: @Himarm If Goku lives forever in order to have infinite offspring, then we have no problem running out of pure Sayins in the first place. ...Due to Goku living forever, and him being pure-blooded.

Comment: @Axlerod then that answered my question, I know it's not pure blooded, hence the half-breed statement.

Comment: yes but by your admission then no one is a pure blood, if we follow an evolutionary progression we are not 100% human we have .000000000000001 % of whatever was before us, or anyother "types" of humans that no longer exist. same with dogs, cats, ect a pure blood has other blood in it along the lines, but they breed that out to such small levels it no longer matters, so if your above a certain threshold youbecome a new pureblood, they regularly make new purebloods of dogs and cats this way.

Comment: @GorchestopherH DNA has a finite number of genes, so it's impossible to get continually asymptotically closer - it would happen long before "forever".

Comment: @Izkata I don't recall saying we'd get asymptotically close by breeding Goku with any female half-saiyan, then Goku with their daughters, etc. I'm saying this is ridiculous.

Comment: @GorchestopherH Ah, I misunderstood why "infinite offspring" was brought up =P

Answer (score -2):

I am sure that there are many more descendants of Kakarot and Vegeta that are never mentioned in either the manga and anime such as the unknown ancestors of Goku jr. The saiyans will reemerge but I am sure that they hide in plain sight practicing their ways behind closed doors waiting to find a home planet once more.

Comment: Um, no, it's explicitly said that Goku, Vegeta, Nappa, and Raditz are the only remaining Saiyans.

Comment: Well of the five which lived, one Bardock is all but unknown to the z-fighters and the other saiyans survivors. There may well be more survivors that are roaming the galaxies.

Comment: There were only four survivors, Bardock didn't survive.  The whole sending him back in time thing to make him the Legendary Super Saiyan is not canon, it's a response to the fan reaction to the character of Bardock.  Likewise, Broly and Pegasus aren't canon either, neither is Vegeta's little brother.

Comment: Canonically, there are four surviving Saiyans, Goku, Vegeta, Nappa, and Raditz.

Comment: The use all sources of information rather than using just one broadens the picture and creates a more vibrant tapestry for us the viewer to marvel at.